# Moving VM to a folder within DataCenter

Tags: powershell, vsphere, powercli

There are two datastores within the vcenter I'm working on. In both datastores, I want to have a folder named simply "Test".

I figured that if I ran `Move-VM -VM VmName -Destination Test`, the VM would be moved to the "Test" folder found within the datastore it resides on. This is proving not to be the case as I'm getting an error for having multiple values for my Destination.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to move VMs to another datastore or having the two folders in question named differently?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a way to specify a Datastore in ``Move-VM`` command? that would probably fix the error

Comment: @4c74356b41 As far as I can tell (and test), the -Datastore flag is used to specify what Datestore you want to move it to. I've tried `Move-VM $vm -Datastore ($vm | Get-Datastore) -Destination Test` but continue to get the "multiple values" error.

Comment: can you do ``-Destination Datastore/Test?``

Comment: `-Destination` is not the property you want, that is going to move your vm to a different datacenter or resource pool, rather than to a different location on the datastore. Honestly I'm not sure it's possible to move VM folders out of the root of each datastore via PowerCli, at least without more than one cmdlet being used as VMWare strongly defaults to datastores with VM folders at the root and you would need to edit the actual VM configuration file to point it to a different path if you moved the VMDK.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio I don't necessarily have to move it out of its datastore. If it's looking in its own datastore for the folder to move to that would be fine. The more pertinent problem is that I can't have two folders of the same name, even though they're in different datastores? I feel like there must be a workaround..

Comment: so I guess my question is why are you using folders on the datastore at all?  what advantage is there to not using vmwares default organization?  the problem here isn't that you have two folders, it's that Move-VM does not support moving VM's around on a datastore, only between datastores.  If you want to move the VM's around the datastore expect to be creating a whole lot more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line worked for what I wanted to do:

```
Move-VM -VM $vmObject -Destination  (($vmObject | Get-Datacenter) | Get-Folder -Name "Test" )
```

Comment: ohh so you meant DataCenter, not DataStore.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Sorry about that.. The original error complained about the Datastore so I was confused. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If there are duplicate folder in Datacenter. You can use below Syntax

$folder = Get-Datacenter -Name "Prod" | Get-Folder -Name "MST" | Get-Folder -Name "Application" | Get-Folder -Name Linux